# Zebra Datepicker not showing validation error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-validate

I'm using the Zebra Datepicker in one of my forms and I'm trying to validate it with the jzaefferer validate plugin. I want the input field to get a red border and I want a error message beneath the input field. The red border is working, but the error message isn't showing. How can I get the error message to show up?

This is my code (the error message should go into .diverror):

```
<div class="input-datepicker">
    <label>Van:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Datum1" class="datepicker" />
</div>
<div class="diverror"></div>
```

Zebra Datepicker places the `<input>` inside a `<span>` and adds a `<button>` under the `<input>` inside the `<span>`.

```
<div class="input-datepicker">
   <label>Van:</label>
   <span class="Zebra_DatePicker_Icon_Wrapper" style="display: block; position:  relative; float: none; top: auto; right: auto; bottom: auto; left: auto;">
   <input class="datepicker error" type="text" name="Datum1" readonly="readonly" style="position: relative; top: auto; right: auto; bottom: auto; left: auto;">
   <button class="Zebra_DatePicker_Icon Zebra_DatePicker_Icon_Inside" type="button" style="top: 23px; left: 233px;">Pick a date</button>
   </span>
</div>
<div class="diverror"></div>
```

I'm not that experienced with jquery but could it be the span that is messing up my appendTo in the example below.

Here's my validation.js:

```
$("#home-verhuur").validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.appendTo( element.parent("div").next("div") );
    },
    ignore: "input[type='text']:hidden",
    onsubmit: true,
    onkeyup: true,
    onclick: true,
    rules: {

        Naam: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        Email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        Product: {
            required: true
        },
        Personen: {
            required: true,
            min: 1
        },
        Datum1: {
            required: true,
        },
        Datum2: {
            required: true,
        },

        },
    messages: {
        Naam: "Vul je voornaam in (minimaal 2 karakters)",
        Email: "Vul een correct Email adres in",
        Product: "Kies een product",
        Personen: "Vul het aantal personen in",
        Datum1: "Kies een begindatum",
        Datum2: "Kies een einddatum",
    }
});
```

All the help is welcome!

Comment: Where is the rest of the code inside `.validate()`?

Comment: Something else must be wrong with your code that you haven't shown us.  It's working fine for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/2g953/  ~  What's all this talk about `span` and `button` when you show us no `span` or `button` elements in the code?

Comment: Also, you should read the documentation for `onclick`, `onkeyup`, and `onsubmit`.  Setting these three options to `true` is not the correct usage:  [_"A boolean `true` is not a valid value"_](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)

Comment: @Sparky: In my original code there is no `<span>` or `<button>`. Zebra_datepicker adds those elements.

Comment: Yes, better, because the _rendered_ code as seen by the DOM is what jQuery is really manipulating.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your *rendered* HTML as constructed by the DOM...

You must change `.parent()` to `.parents()`, since the target `div` is now another level higher...

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    error.appendTo(element.parents("div").next("div"));
},
```

DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/2g953/1/

Comment: The error message is now showing. Thanks! But now the other error messages are showing up more than once in other `div`'s. This has something to do with changing `.parent()` to `.parents()`, but i don't know how to fix it? http://jsfiddle.net/2g953/7/

Comment: @KlaasvnA, you fix it by putting a conditional _inside_ the `errorPlacement`.  Like `if` this element, put it here, `else if` some other kind of element, put it there.